# javascript form validation not works, and all data are posted to php

Tags: php, javascript

Here is html part.I have write it in a different file and javascript into a different .js file which i have included into the html appropiate place. All the information goes to data base through the php and mysql, php filename is registration.php

```
<form action="registration.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" name="myForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ><label><strong>First Name</strong></label></td>
            <td>
            <input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" onfocus="hideerror()" ></td>
            <td style="width: 240px">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label><strong>Last Name</strong></label></td>
            <td>
            <input name="lname" type="text" style="width: 177px" id="lname" onfocus="hideerror()"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label><strong>Email</strong></label></td>
            <td>
            <input name="email" type="text" id="email" style="width: 178px" onfocus="hideerror()"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label id="Label1"><strong>Confirm Email</strong></label></td>
            <td >
            <input name="cemail" type="text" id="cemail" style="width: 177px" onchange="compare_mail();" onfocus="hideerror()"></td>
            <td  ><label id="message1"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label id="Label1"><strong>Password</strong></label></td>
            <td style="height: 33px;">
            <input name="password" type="password" maxlength="12" style="height: 26px; width: 177px;" id="password" onfocus="hideerror()"></td>
            <td >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label id="Label1"><strong>Confirm Password</strong></label></td>
            <td >
            <input name="cpassword" type="password" maxlength="12" onchange="compare_password();" id="cpassword" class="auto-style15" style="width: 179px" onfocus="hideerror()"></td>
            <td ><label id="message2"></label>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label id="Label1"><strong>Mobile Number</strong></label></td>
            <td>
            <input name="mobile" type="text" maxlength="10" style="width: 177px" id="mobile" onfocus="hideerror()"></td>
            <td ><label id="mobile_error"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 152px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 240px">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input name="register" type="submit" id="register" value="Register"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label id="massege" style="visibility:hidden">Please Fill out all the fields</label></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
```

Here is my javascript validate function

```
function validate(){
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var x1=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
var x2=document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
var x3=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var x4=document.forms["myForm"]["cemail"].value;
var x5=document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
var x6=document.forms["myForm"]["cpassword"].value;
var x7=document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value;

        if(!x1||!x2||!x3||!x4||!x5||!x6||!x7)
        {
            document.getElementById('massege').style.visibility='visible';
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('message').style.visibility='hidden';
        } 
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(!atpos||!dotpos)
        {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;

        }
         if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
         {
             alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
             return false;
         }

         if(x7.length<10)
         {
            document.getElementById('mobile_error').innerHTML="Mobile number should be 10 digits";
         }
         if(x5!=x6)
         {
            document.getElementById('message2').innerHTML="Password does't match";
            return false;
         }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, it'd be worth checking over this yourself first, considering there are simple typos on this. `massege` should be `message` ... or vice versa, just choose one... XD

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, I suggest adding a `<input type='button'>` to the page that has a onclick event that calls the validate() function. This will allow you to run the validation function without submitting the form. Most likely the problem is an error in the validate function and the page is submitting because the function errors out instead of returning true/false as expected. The page is submitting before you can see that there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

There's typo:

```
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('message').style.visibility='hidden';
    }
```

it should be "massege".

**Suggestion** : please use firebug or chrome's developer tools for debugging javascript code.